# Groovy - ArrayList that increments item amount instead of re-adding

Tags: arraylist, groovy

I have two array lists, (which I'm gonna simplify for this question) that look like this:

```
def originalList = [[name: "Ben", age: 21, weight: 80], [name: "Martin", age: 36, weight: 99], [name: "Sammy", age: 18, weight: 65], [name: "Ben", age: 28, weight: 75], [name: "Ben", age: 28, weight: 120]]
```

The other one I'll call `newList` and it starts out empty, i.e. `def newList = []` but the properties `name`, `age` and `occurrences` will be added.

Now what I want to do is loop through `originalList` and add its items to `newList` but if `newList` already contains an item with the same name **and** age property I want to increment the `occurrences` property for the item, e.g:

```
def newList = [[name: "Ben", age: 21, occurrences: 1], [name: "Martin", age: 36, occurrences: 1], [name: "Sammy", age: 18, occurrences: 1], [name: "Ben", age: 28, occurrences: 2]]
```

How would I go about getting this done? Here's what I've tried.

```
originalList.each {
    newList.eachWithIndex { nl, i ->
        if(nl.name.equals(it.name) && nl.age == it.age) {
            nl.occurrances++
        } else {
            newList.add([name: it.name, age: it.age, occurrances: 0])
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like it's not working coz the `newList.eachWithIndex` never loops coz it starts out empty and coz it never loops it can never increment the `occurrences` property or add items to the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go this way e.g.:

```
def originalList = [
    [name: "Ben", age: 21, weight: 80], 
    [name: "Martin", age: 36, weight: 99], 
    [name: "Sammy", age: 18, weight: 65], 
    [name: "Ben", age: 28, weight: 75], 
    [name: "Ben", age: 28, weight: 120]
]

originalList
    .groupBy( { it.name }, { it.age } )
    .collect { k1, v1 -> v1.collect { k2, v2 -> [name: k1, age: k2, occurrences: v2.size()] } }
    .flatten()
```

It the first step input is grouped by both `name` and `age` which results in a `Map`, then `values` (`v1`) for each key `k1` is processed to get the stats. Since the mentioned operation results in nested `List`, `flatten()` is called at the very end.

Comment: Or just get rid of the first layer by grouping by the set of k/v you are interested: `originalList.groupBy{it.subMap("name","age")}.collect{k,os->k+[occurances: os.size()]}`

Comment: @cfrick, nice! Do you work with groovy on a daily basis?

Comment: Or `originalList.groupBy { "$it.name::$it.age" }.values().collect { it.head() + [occurrences: it.size()] }`

Answer (score 0):

Just fixing the bugs in your original algorithm (using a map is way more efficient, though!):

```
originalList.each {
    def found=false
    newList.eachWithIndex { nl, i ->
        if(nl.name.equals(it.name) && nl.age == it.age) {
            nl.occurrances++
            found = true
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
       newList.add([name: it.name, age: it.age, occurrances: 1])
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Version with map, as requested...

```
def map = [:]

originalList.each {
    def key = it.name+"@"+it.age  // or something better, keeping it simple here

    if (map[key]) {
      map[key].occurances++
    }
    else {
      def entry = [name: it.name, age: it.age, occurrances: 1]
      map[key] = entry
      newList.add(entry)
    }
}
```

Comment: What would the hashmap version of the above look like? If you don't mind adding it to your answer?

Answer (score -1):

I am not a groovy developer, so I'll write code snippet in java. Please translate yourself.

```
Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();//this map stores name and occurances

for(Employee e: originaleList){
    int oldCount=map.get(e.getName()) == null ? 0 : map.get(e.getName());
    map.put(e.getName(), oldCount + 1);

    newList.add(new Employee(e.getName(), e.getAge(), map.get(e.getName())));
    }
```